# How to test not ActiveRecord models with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

For example, I have a very simple model of a Card, for a popular card game. On initialize I want to give it a value and a suit (unique for every one of 36 cards). Here is my model:

```
class Card

  attr_accessor :suit, :value

  @@values = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'B', 'D', 'K', 'T'] * 4
  @@suites = ['B', 'C', 'P', 'H'] * 9

  def initialize
    @suit = get_rundom_suit_or_value @@suites
    @value = get_rundom_suit_or_value @@values
  end

  private 

    def get_rundom_suit_or_value given_array
      given_array.delete_at(given_array.index(given_array.sample)) unless given_array.nil? || given_array.empty?
    end
end
```

I try to test it from console, and the result was satisfying:

```
c = Card.new
 => #<Card:0x007f8e34050428 @suit="H", @value="D"> 
2.0.0-p0 :024 > c.value
 => "D"
```

But rspec tests don't give me the same result. Here they are:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Card' do
  it 'has @suit value on initialize' do  
    c = Card.new
    c.suit.should_not be nil
  end
  it 'has @value value on initialize' do  
    c = Card.new
    c.value.should_not be nil
  end
end
```

And re result:

```
Card has @suit value on initialize
     Failure/Error: c.suit.should_not be nil

       expected not #<NilClass:8> => nil
                got #<NilClass:8> => nil
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `c.suit.should_not be_nil`

Comment: `expected: not nil
            got: nil`

Comment: What's in your spec_helper.rb? Do you define another `Card` class somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I put your code into a file and run it, I get no errors. What you have should work perfectly fine already - at least it does for me.

Comment: same error `Card suit should not be nil
     Failure/Error: its(:suit) { should_not be_nil }
       expected: not nil
            got: nil`  I double check this in console and still getting this error. From a console I get `2.0.0-p0 :001 > c = Card.new
 => #<Card:0x007fefcc83fce8 @suit="B", @value="T">`

Comment: I'm sorry, your original syntax was perfectly fine. In fact, your code works perfectly when I run it. No spec failures, just successes. Changing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You are right, I test it as an file, outside from rails ENV, and I get success :). the `Jakob S` comment maybe is the answer to this issue.  `Card class somewhere? –  1 hour ago`